# SSIS: convert ISO 8601 string to datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I have a CSV falt file I'm trying to import using SSIS.  The date string is in the format **20170215T000002** - this looks like ISO 8601, so I'm pretty sure I should just be able to map it to a *datetime* column type in SQL, but I lose all of the time data and just get the date component (correctly parsed).

Any advice on how to get this text element into a *datetime* format in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the date column name is `inColumn`

In the DataflowTask, Add a script component , Mark `inColumn` as input column, add a new Output column `outColumn` with dataType DT_DBTIMESTAMP

In the script, in `Input0_ProcessInputRow` sub use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) Function as follow:

```
Row.inColumn =  DateTime.ParseExact(Row.inColumn,"yyyyMMddTHHmmss",New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think ISO 8601 has colons for the time separator.

Assuming that you are using SQL Server, this should work:

```
select convert(datetime,
               stuff(stuff(col, 14, 0, ':'), 12, 0, ':'),
               126)
```

Comment: It would seem it does, but using the suggestion from @Hadi above, I managed to get it to work.